A question about rapid ultrafilters
Recall that an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\omega$ is called rapid if for every $f \in \omega^\omega$, there is an $X \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $|X \cap f(n)| \leq n$ for all $n \in \omega$.
Equivalently, $\mathcal{U}$ is rapid if for every $\{P_n\}_{n \in \omega} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\omega)$, where each $P_n$ is finite, there is $X \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $|X \cap P_n| \leq n$ for all $n \in \omega$.
Now for a map $f \in \omega^\omega$ with $f(0) > 0$, define $\operatorname{exp}(f)(0)=f(0)$ and $\operatorname{exp}(f)(n+1)=f(\operatorname{exp}(f)(n))$. Tom defines the notion of an almost-rapid ultrafilter in this paper as: $\mathcal{U}$ is called almost-rapid if for every $f \in \omega^\omega$, there is $X \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $f \leq^* \operatorname{exp}(f_X)$, where $f_X$ is the increasing enumeration of $X$. It is shown in the same paper that this is equivalent to: For every $\{P_n\}_{n \in \omega} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\omega)$, where each $P_n$ is finite, there is $X \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $|X \cap P_n| \leq \operatorname{exp}(f_X)(n-1)$ for all $n \in \omega$, where $\operatorname{exp}(f_X)(-1)=0$.
I might be missing something but what I want to ask is, if $\mathcal{U}$ is defined to give witnesses to such partitions, but this time with the bound $|X \cap P_n| \leq f_{X \setminus \{0\}}(n-1)$ (where $f(-1)=0$), will this be equivalent to one of the previous notions? It now stands between them, but I don’t know if it is equivalent to one of them. Thank you.
